# Conditions are not working properly

Tags: javascript

If condition is true but not working. `x.innerHTML` already has `clicked me` content inside it but the condition is not responding to it.
When I run the code and click on the div tag it shows me `job is done` while it should be `click me \n click me again`.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("something") ;
x.addEventListener("click", istFunction) ;

function istFunction() {
  if ( x.innerHTML == "click me" ) {
    x.innerHTML += "<br> click me again" ;
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "click me <br> click me again") {
    x.innerHTML = "thank you" ;
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "thank you" ) {
    x.innerHTML = "good bye" ; 
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "good bye") { 
    x.style.display = "none" ; 
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "") {
    x.innerHTML == "click me" ;
  } else { x.innerHTML = "job is done" ;
         }
}
```

```html
<div class="dclass" id="something">
click me
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<span>` tags and whitespace:

```
<div class="dclass" id="something">click me</div>
```

Comment: even though, problem is not fixed.

Comment: it's the double comparison of `if ( x.innerHTML == "click me" )` in your example.

Comment: double comparison is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the first time you click XXX `x.innerHTML` returns `<span>click me</span>`. You can remove the `span` element or use `x.innerText`

Comment: `innerText` is nonstandard and doesn't work cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you have a couple of problems, one is that innerhtml will contain the span. If you just remove the span it will contain a prepending newline unless you bring it all up on a single line.  Secondly you try to match "click me again with a space before the 
 but you didn't add one when you set it.  Here is a codepen that I think demonstrates what you are trying to accomplish: http://codepen.io/socketwiz/pen/wapqyQ

```
var x = document.getElementById("something");
x.addEventListener("click", istFunction);

function istFunction(e) {
  console.log(x.innerHTML);
  if (x.innerHTML == "click me") {
    x.innerHTML += " <br> click me again";
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "click me <br> click me again") {
    x.innerHTML = "thank you";
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "thank you") {
    x.innerHTML = "good bye";
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "good bye") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else if (x.innerHTML == "") {
    x.innerHTML == "click me";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "job is done";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using `innerHTML` which will contain the html for the `<span>`. Try `innerText`.

```
<div class="dclass" id="something">
<span>click me</span>
</div>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("something") ;
x.addEventListener("click", istFunction) ;

function istFunction() {
    console.log("innerHTML:",x.innerHTML)
    console.log("innerText:",x.innerText)
}
</script>
```

output:

```
innerHTML: <span>click me</span>
innerText: click me
```

Comment: I removed the span tag and white spacing but it still not working. But I am still using x.innerHTML.

Comment: @Hemant try using `console.log` to compare the output each time. Check for extra spaces and see if what you are expecting is really what is being checked.